# Well, well, well

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, word-request, expressions

How to say this expression in Latin!?

Expressing surprise: *Well, well, well! It is here (when smth lost and found)!*

Expressing sarcasm: *Well, well, well... And what now!?*

Expressing begining: *Well, well, well... Here we go!*

And *more*.

This expression in a lot of languages have this structure: *Word, word, word...* or weakened to *Word, word...*

Sometimes as synonym to *¡hmm*.